# Set component position

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm going to set the position of a component (for example, view) on the screen

I was able to get the location of the components by onLayout and measure, but I could not find an example for setting a component on the screen.

Like the image below:

[image: searchbox]

When the content is scrolled, the search section is stopped above, and the rest of the sections are scrolled below it.
What instructions are needed to implement the search section? The thing that I thought was the use of the measure, but I do not know how to set the positions of a view

please guide me

Comment: Did you try position things with `style` ? you can read: [Style](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style) and [Layout with Flexbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox)

Comment: @FabriBertani i update post with an image

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your searchbox inside the scrollview